# Required isn't being rendered in the h:inputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

Just a curiosity, when I have an h:inputText with the attribute required set to true, it is rendered the following way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="indexFormId" value="indexFormId" />
```

The h:inputText (just an example):

```
<h:inputText styleClass="form-control"  maxlength="50" id="id"  value="#{bean.id}" required="true" />
```

Why am I not getting the attribute required? For example like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="indexFormId" value="indexFormId" required/>
```

Is there anyway to get the required attribute rendered?
Thanks!

Comment: why should it? Where did you read that 'required' is not an existing valid attribute of the plain html input

Comment: @Kukeltje: since HTML5 it is: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-required.php It's however only validated client side, far from robust ;)

Comment: @BalusC: ooops thanks... and yes, far from robust, like all client-side js frameworks ;-)